# SFML installation opengl

Tags: opengl, sfml

I have to install SFML 2.1 . We need it for opengl and it has to be a static build . I have been through tutorial so many times and re done it over and over again but I can't get it too work.

I do the include / lib directories properly in the "All Configurations" configuration. Then I do the Preprocessor in "Debug" configuration , 'SFML_STATIC'. The I do the additional dependencies "sfml-window-s-d.lib" in debug configuration and "sfml-window-s.lib" in release but still get ": fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals" as an error. The project is also a "Win32 Console Application" and I have tried "Application Type" as 'Windows Application' , 'Console Application' and 'Static Library' .

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Did you include sfml-graphics-s.lib sfml-window-s.lib and sfml-system-s.lib in THIS order? When you use the OpenGL example make sure you include opengl32.lib too.

Comment: No I didn't know there was an order. And the opengl32.lib would be "opengl32-s-d.lib" for debug and "opengl32-s.lib" for release ?

Comment: No use `opengl32.lib`. opengl32.dll is in your system32 folder and is automatically dynamic-linked by windows.

Comment: As joschuck points out: `opengl32.lib` is a Microsoft library. It ships with exactly **1** configuration - **Release | Dynamic**. You cannot statically link to opengl32, nor would you want to. That DLL is part of Windows, and it is responsible for hiding the details Microsoft Windows uses to communicate with the display driver's implementation of OpenGL. It contains the GDI (software-based 1.1) implementation of OpenGL and provides the WGL / ICD extension mechanism needed to get hardware-accelerated OpenGL on the platform.